# (Python) algorithm to randomly select a key based on proportionality/weight

Tags: python

I'm a bit at a loss as to how to find a clean algorithm for doing the following:

Suppose I have a dict k:

```
>>> k = {'A': 68, 'B': 62, 'C': 47, 'D': 16, 'E': 81}
```

I now want to randomly select one of these keys, based on the 'weight' they have in the total (i.e. sum) amount of keys.

```
>>> sum(k.values()) 
>>> 274
```

So that there's a

```
>>> 68.0/274.0
>>> 0.24817518248175183
```

24.81% percent change that A is selected.

How would you write an algorithm that takes care of this? In other words, that makes sure that on 10.000 random picks, A will be selected 2.481 times?

Comment: Note that in your last sentence, you cannot guarantee that A will be picked exactly 2481 times if you want to choose letters independently at random with a constant probability. If you want a guarantee like that you should create a fixed pool of 10000 letters in the distribution you require and draw letters without replacement.

Comment: I see. This seems to be related to my remark to Paul Hankin's code. Thanks for clarifying (and setting my mind at ease).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Here's a weighted choice function, with some code that exercises it.

```
import random

def WeightedPick(d):
    r = random.uniform(0, sum(d.itervalues()))
    s = 0.0
    for k, w in d.iteritems():
        s += w
        if r < s: return k
    return k

def Test():
    k = {'A': 68, 'B': 62, 'C': 47, 'D': 16, 'E': 81}
    results = {}
    for x in xrange(10000):
        p = WeightedPick(k)
        results[p] = results.get(p, 0) + 1
    print results

Test()
```

Comment: Great, thanks! This code returns exactly the right results. Thanks for your quick replies, everyone.

Comment: But still: the exact weight is not attained (a test with 100 million rnd's gave me 24.8203% for "A"). Should I worry about this (i.e. is the code to blame?) or is this just the nature of randomness?

Comment: @LaundroMat Yes, the probability converges as the number of trials increases but will never be exact. You can read about variance or standard deviation to learn what you can expect.

Answer (score 10):

This should do the trick:

```
>>> k = {'A': 68, 'B': 62, 'C': 47, 'D': 16, 'E': 81}
>>> import random
>>> def weighted_pick(dic):
...     total = sum(dic.itervalues())
...     pick = random.randint(0, total-1)
...     tmp = 0
...     for key, weight in dic.iteritems():
...         tmp += weight
...         if pick < tmp:
...             return key
```

Comment: Why do you do total-1?

Comment: @user2767074 because `randint` is inclusive.

Answer (score 5):

The algorithm would be this..

Select a number randomly between 1 and 274. To do that, call a rand() funciton (assume it returns a value between 0 and 1), multiply rand() by 274. The resulting value should now be in a range. If its between 1 and 68, select A, if its between 69 and 130 select B and so on. This way, your probability stays alive and your operation succeeds.

PS: I am a Java guy, dont know the syntax of Python.

Comment: If it exists you should use a function/method that returns an integer in a certain range instead of scaling a floating-point value to stay clear of aliasing problems.

Comment: Exactly, the scaling method would be a cast. I mean, i would typically cast the resulting value from the rand method by casting it to an integer.

Answer (score 2):

The simplest way of doing this when your weights are relatively small integers (such as in your example) is to build a long string containing all the characters in the appropriate weights and choose a character at random from it:

```
import random
d = {'A': 68, 'B': 62, 'C': 47, 'D': 16, 'E': 81}
s = ''.join(k*v for k,v in d.items())
random.choice(s)
```

Note though that this method will use quite a lot of memory if your weights are large, in which case you might prefer a different solution.

Answer (score 2):

one should also look at
[this link](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generate/scipy.stats.rv_discrete.html)

make two list for k, say `xk` and `yk`

```
from scipy import stats
custm = stats.rv_discrete(name='test', values=(xk, yk))
custm.rvs(size=1)
```

Answer (score -1):

I've developed an algorithm a few years ago, with application in Perl and SQL, you can read about it [here](http://use.perl.org/~bart/journal/33630), complete with analysis and tests why it (most likely) is correct.

The concept is simple: for each item, pick a random number, pull it through some function that depends on the items' weight, and pick the item with the lowest value.

That function is:

```
x[i] = -log(1 - rand())/weight[i]
```

Comment: Clever trick, but it's a horrible idea to use this in practice. It's not obviously correct (despite the pages of maths proof), and it's expensive to compute (it requires N rand() calls, and N log() calls). Also, it's likely to have numerical problems. When 1 - rand() is close to 0, the log can be arbitrarily large; perhaps overflowing.