# Generate random numbers with a given (numerical) distribution

Tags: python, module, random

I have a file with some probabilities for different values e.g.:

```
1 0.1
2 0.05
3 0.05
4 0.2
5 0.4
6 0.2
```

I would like to generate random numbers using this distribution. Does an existing module that handles this exist? It's fairly simple to code on your own (build the cumulative density function, generate a random value [0,1] and pick the corresponding value) but it seems like this should be a common problem and probably someone has created a function/module for it.

I need this because I want to generate a list of birthdays (which do not follow any distribution in the standard `random` module).

Comment: Other than `random.choice()`?  You build the master list with the proper number of occurrences and choose one.  This is a duplicate question, of course.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Random weighted choice](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2073235/random-weighted-choice)

Comment: @S.Lott isn't that very memory intensive for big differences in the distribution?

Comment: @S.Lott: Your choice method would probably be fine for small numbers of occurrences but I'd rather avoid creating huge lists when it is not necessary.

Comment: @S.Lott: The question you linked to is related, but I asked about existing methods while the answers to that question use a "homegrown" CDF approach I already mentioned.

Comment: @Lucasmus: define "big".  @pafcu: define "huge".  This will work delightfully well until you fill up all of memory with the distribution table.  Will you really have billions of choices?  Really?  For any practical simulation, a few thousand values in a choice table essentially nothing.

Comment: @S.Lott: OK, about 10000*365 = 3650000 = 3.6 million elements. I'm not sure about the memory usage in Python, but it's at least 3.6M*4B =14.4MB. Not a huge amount, but not something you should ignore either when there is an equally simple method that does not require the extra memory.

Comment: @S.Lott for example one value with chance of occurrence 0.2 and one value with chance of occurrence 0.0037. Requires the list to contain 10000 elements (2000x the first, 37x the second) etc.

Comment: @Lucasmus: Isn't it actually a question of significant numbers? One rate of 0.1234 and another with 0.1235 would require 1234+1235=2469 elements, even though the difference in chances is small.

Comment: @pafcu: I think that requires 10000 elements as there are also the elements that cover `1-0.1234-0.1235`

Comment: @Lucasmus: Sure, I just wanted to point out that it's not a question of how different the probabilities are, just the number of significant numbers in them.

Comment: @pafcu: Ah yes okay, you're right :)

Comment: @S.Lott won't work if probabilities are not rational numbers. What if I have two items, one with probability sqrt(2)/2 and the other with 1 - sqrt(2)/2? If I want to sample from this distribution with 10 decimal places precision in the relative frequencies, I'd have to have a master table with around 10^10 repeated items. There are MUCH more efficient ways of doing that, and they are quite simple. No need of master tables.

Comment: If `O(log n)` `__getitem__` is ok then you only need `O(n)` memory regardless the precision. Code example: [WeightedPopulation](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13052108/4279)

Answer (score 211, accepted):

[`scipy.stats.rv_discrete`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.rv_discrete.html) might be what you want.  You can supply your probabilities via the `values` parameter.  You can then use the `rvs()` method of the distribution object to generate random numbers.

As pointed out by Eugene Pakhomov in the comments, you can also pass a `p` keyword parameter to [`numpy.random.choice()`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/random/generated/numpy.random.choice.html), e.g.

```
numpy.random.choice(numpy.arange(1, 7), p=[0.1, 0.05, 0.05, 0.2, 0.4, 0.2])
```

If you are using Python 3.6 or above, you can use `random.choices()` from the standard library – see the [answer by Mark Dickinson](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41852266/5987).

Comment: On my machine `numpy.random.choice()` is almost 20 times faster.

Comment: @EugenePakhomov I don't quite understand your comment.  So a function doing something completely different is faster than the one I suggested.  My recommendation would still be to use the function that does what you want rather than a function that does something else, even if the function that does something else is faster.

Comment: it does exactly the same w.r.t. to the original question. E.g.: `numpy.random.choice(numpy.arange(1, 7), p=[0.1, 0.05, 0.05, 0.2, 0.4, 0.2])`

Comment: Surprisingly, rv_discrete.rvs() works in O(len(p) * size) time and memory! While choice() seems to run in optimal O(len(p) + log(len(p)) * size) time.

Comment: If you're using **Python 3.6** or newer there's [**another answer**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41852266/5987) that doesn't require any addon packages.

Answer (score 194):

Since Python 3.6, there's a solution for this in Python's standard library, namely [`random.choices`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/random.html#random.choices).

Example usage: let's set up a population and weights matching those in the OP's question:

```
>>> from random import choices
>>> population = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
>>> weights = [0.1, 0.05, 0.05, 0.2, 0.4, 0.2]
```

Now `choices(population, weights)` generates a single sample, contained in a list of length 1:

```
>>> choices(population, weights)
[4]
```

The optional keyword-only argument `k` allows one to request more than one sample at once. This is valuable because there's some preparatory work that `random.choices` has to do every time it's called, prior to generating any samples; by generating many samples at once, we only have to do that preparatory work once. Here we generate a million samples, and use `collections.Counter` to check that the distribution we get roughly matches the weights we gave.

```
>>> million_samples = choices(population, weights, k=10**6)
>>> from collections import Counter
>>> Counter(million_samples)
Counter({5: 399616, 6: 200387, 4: 200117, 1: 99636, 3: 50219, 2: 50025})
```

Comment: Is there a Python 2.7 version to this?

Comment: @abbas786: Not built in, but the other answers to this question should all work on Python 2.7. You could also look up the Python 3 source for random.choices and copy that, if so inclined.

Comment: For me `random.choices` with `k=1` returns a list of length one, i.e., `choices(population, weights)` ought to return `[4]`

Comment: @christianbrodbeck: Thanks, fixed. I almost always generate those snippets by copy-and-paste, so obviously something went wrong here.

Comment: Thanks! I was wondering whether it’s a version issue but that explains it.

Comment: Is there a way to guarantee that the sample will not contain the same member twice

Answer (score 33):

An advantage to generating the list using CDF is that you can use binary search. While you need O(n) time and space for preprocessing, you can get k numbers in O(k log n). Since normal Python lists are inefficient, you can use `array` module.

If you insist on constant space, you can do the following; O(n) time, O(1) space.

```
def random_distr(l):
    r = random.uniform(0, 1)
    s = 0
    for item, prob in l:
        s += prob
        if s >= r:
            return item
    return item  # Might occur because of floating point inaccuracies
```

Comment: The order of the (item, prob) pairs in the list matters in your implementation, right?

Comment: @stackoverflowuser2010: It shouldn't matter (modulo errors in floating point)

Comment: Nice. I found this to be 30% faster than scipy.stats.rv_discrete.

Comment: Quite a few times this function will throw a KeyError because the last line.

Comment: @DrunkenMaster: I don't understand. Are you aware `l[-1]` returns the last element of the list?

Comment: return l[-1], returns 'item' or the last ordered pair from 'l', unlike the other return statement, in your code @sdcvvc

Comment: @sdcvvc: I think 'item' is out of the scope of the for loop. Should be l[-1][0] by your logic; assuming l is a list of ordered pairs or the like.

Comment: @Vaibhav: in Python last index is still available after the loop. I've considered `l[-1][0]` but the second form seems more obvious to the reader.

Comment: I see, sorry, i'm not a pro in python.. it's fine then.

Answer (score 18):

(OK, I know you are asking for shrink-wrap, but maybe those home-grown solutions just weren't succinct enough for your liking. :-)

```
pdf = [(1, 0.1), (2, 0.05), (3, 0.05), (4, 0.2), (5, 0.4), (6, 0.2)]
cdf = [(i, sum(p for j,p in pdf if j < i)) for i,_ in pdf]
R = max(i for r in [random.random()] for i,c in cdf if c <= r)
```

I pseudo-confirmed that this works by eyeballing the output of this expression:

```
sorted(max(i for r in [random.random()] for i,c in cdf if c <= r)
       for _ in range(1000))
```

Comment: This looks impressive. Just to put things in context, here are the results from 3 consecutive executions of the above code:

['Count of 1 with prob: 0.1 is: 113', 'Count of 2 with prob: 0.05 is: 55', 'Count of 3 with prob: 0.05 is: 50', 'Count of 4 with prob: 0.2 is: 201', 'Count of 5 with prob: 0.4 is: 388', 'Count of 6 with prob: 0.2 is: 193']..............['Count of 1 with prob: 0.1 is: 77', 'Count of 2 with prob: 0.05 is: 60', 'Count of 3 with prob: 0.05 is: 51', 'Count of 4 with prob: 0.2 is: 193', 'Count of 5 with prob: 0.4 is: 438', 'Count of 6 with prob: 0.2 is: 181'] ............. and

Comment: ['Count of 1 with prob: 0.1 is: 84', 'Count of 2 with prob: 0.05 is: 52', 'Count of 3 with prob: 0.05 is: 53', 'Count of 4 with prob: 0.2 is: 210', 'Count of 5 with prob: 0.4 is: 405', 'Count of 6 with prob: 0.2 is: 196']

Comment: A question, how do I return max(i... , if 'i' is an object?

Comment: @Vaibhav `i` isn't an object.

Answer (score 18):

Maybe it is kind of late. But you can use [`numpy.random.choice()`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.random.choice.html#numpy.random.choice), passing the `p` parameter:

```
val = numpy.random.choice(numpy.arange(1, 7), p=[0.1, 0.05, 0.05, 0.2, 0.4, 0.2])
```

Comment: The OP doesn't want to use `random.choice()` - see the comments.

Comment: `numpy.random.choice()` is completely different from `random.choice()` and supports probability distribution.

Comment: Can't I use a function to define p? Why would I want to define it with numbers?

Comment: If you want to sample from a specific distribution you should use a statistical package like `scipy.stats`or `statsmodels` and then get samples from the specific probability distribution you want to sample from. This question concerns the case of a user defined discrete distribution.

Answer (score 10):

I wrote a solution for **drawing random samples from a custom continuous distribution**.

I needed this for a similar use-case to yours (i.e. generating random dates with a given probability distribution).

You just need the funtion `random_custDist` and the line `samples=random_custDist(x0,x1,custDist=custDist,size=1000)`. The rest is decoration ^^.

```
import numpy as np

#funtion
def random_custDist(x0,x1,custDist,size=None, nControl=10**6):
    #genearte a list of size random samples, obeying the distribution custDist
    #suggests random samples between x0 and x1 and accepts the suggestion with probability custDist(x)
    #custDist noes not need to be normalized. Add this condition to increase performance. 
    #Best performance for max_{x in [x0,x1]} custDist(x) = 1
    samples=[]
    nLoop=0
    while len(samples)<size and nLoop<nControl:
        x=np.random.uniform(low=x0,high=x1)
        prop=custDist(x)
        assert prop>=0 and prop<=1
        if np.random.uniform(low=0,high=1) <=prop:
            samples += [x]
        nLoop+=1
    return samples

#call
x0=2007
x1=2019
def custDist(x):
    if x<2010:
        return .3
    else:
        return (np.exp(x-2008)-1)/(np.exp(2019-2007)-1)
samples=random_custDist(x0,x1,custDist=custDist,size=1000)
print(samples)

#plot
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
#hist
bins=np.linspace(x0,x1,int(x1-x0+1))
hist=np.histogram(samples, bins )[0]
hist=hist/np.sum(hist)
plt.bar( (bins[:-1]+bins[1:])/2, hist, width=.96, label='sample distribution')
#dist
grid=np.linspace(x0,x1,100)
discCustDist=np.array([custDist(x) for x in grid]) #distrete version
discCustDist*=1/(grid[1]-grid[0])/np.sum(discCustDist)
plt.plot(grid,discCustDist,label='custom distribustion (custDist)', color='C1', linewidth=4)
#decoration
plt.legend(loc=3,bbox_to_anchor=(1,0))
plt.show()
```

[image: Continuous custom distribution and discrete sample distribution]

The performance of this solution is improvable for sure, but I prefer readability.

Comment: ```assert prop>=0 and prop<=1
```
Why would the density of a continuous distribution be under 1 ?

Answer (score 2):

Make a list of items, based on their `weights`:

```
items = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
probabilities= [0.1, 0.05, 0.05, 0.2, 0.4, 0.2]
# if the list of probs is normalized (sum(probs) == 1), omit this part
prob = sum(probabilities) # find sum of probs, to normalize them
c = (1.0)/prob # a multiplier to make a list of normalized probs
probabilities = map(lambda x: c*x, probabilities)
print probabilities

ml = max(probabilities, key=lambda x: len(str(x)) - str(x).find('.'))
ml = len(str(ml)) - str(ml).find('.') -1
amounts = [ int(x*(10**ml)) for x in probabilities]
itemsList = list()
for i in range(0, len(items)): # iterate through original items
  itemsList += items[i:i+1]*amounts[i]

# choose from itemsList randomly
print itemsList
```

An optimization may be to normalize amounts by the greatest common divisor, to make the target list smaller.

Also, [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2570690/python-algorithm-to-randomly-select-a-key-based-on-proportionality-weight) might be interesting.

Comment: If the list of items is large this might use a lot of extra memory.

Comment: @pafcu Agreed. Just a solution, the second which came to my mind (the first one was to search for something like "weight probability python" :) ).

Answer (score 1):

Another answer, probably faster :)

```
distribution = [(1, 0.2), (2, 0.3), (3, 0.5)]  
# init distribution  
dlist = []  
sumchance = 0  
for value, chance in distribution:  
    sumchance += chance  
    dlist.append((value, sumchance))  
assert sumchance == 1.0 # not good assert because of float equality  

# get random value  
r = random.random()  
# for small distributions use lineair search  
if len(distribution) < 64: # don't know exact speed limit  
    for value, sumchance in dlist:  
        if r < sumchance:  
            return value  
else:  
    # else (not implemented) binary search algorithm
```

Comment: Dose the `distribution` list need to be sorted by probability?

Comment: Doesn't need to be, but it will perform the fastest if it is sorted by probability biggest first.

Answer (score 1):

```
from __future__ import division
import random
from collections import Counter


def num_gen(num_probs):
    # calculate minimum probability to normalize
    min_prob = min(prob for num, prob in num_probs)
    lst = []
    for num, prob in num_probs:
        # keep appending num to lst, proportional to its probability in the distribution
        for _ in range(int(prob/min_prob)):
            lst.append(num)
    # all elems in lst occur proportional to their distribution probablities
    while True:
        # pick a random index from lst
        ind = random.randint(0, len(lst)-1)
        yield lst[ind]
```

Verification:

```
gen = num_gen([(1, 0.1),
               (2, 0.05),
               (3, 0.05),
               (4, 0.2),
               (5, 0.4),
               (6, 0.2)])
lst = []
times = 10000
for _ in range(times):
    lst.append(next(gen))
# Verify the created distribution:
for item, count in Counter(lst).iteritems():
    print '%d has %f probability' % (item, count/times)

1 has 0.099737 probability
2 has 0.050022 probability
3 has 0.049996 probability 
4 has 0.200154 probability
5 has 0.399791 probability
6 has 0.200300 probability
```

Answer (score 1):

based on other solutions, you generate accumulative distribution (as integer or float whatever you like), then you can use bisect to make it fast

this is a simple example (I used integers here)

```
l=[(20, 'foo'), (60, 'banana'), (10, 'monkey'), (10, 'monkey2')]
def get_cdf(l):
    ret=[]
    c=0
    for i in l: c+=i[0]; ret.append((c, i[1]))
    return ret

def get_random_item(cdf):
    return cdf[bisect.bisect_left(cdf, (random.randint(0, cdf[-1][0]),))][1]

cdf=get_cdf(l)
for i in range(100): print get_random_item(cdf),
```

the `get_cdf` function would convert it from 20, 60, 10, 10 into 20, 20+60, 20+60+10, 20+60+10+10

now we pick a random number up to 20+60+10+10 using `random.randint` then we use bisect to get the actual value in a fast way

Answer (score 0):

you might want to have a look at NumPy [Random sampling distributions](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/routines.random.html)

Comment: The numpy functions also seem to only support a limited number of distributions with no support for specifying your own.

Comment: updated link https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.14.0/reference/routines.random.html instead of  http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/routines.random.html

Answer (score 0):

None of these answers is particularly clear or simple.

Here is a clear, simple method that is guaranteed to work.

**accumulate_normalize_probabilities** takes a dictionary `p` that maps symbols to probabilities **OR** frequencies. It outputs usable list of tuples from which to do selection.

```
def accumulate_normalize_values(p):
        pi = p.items() if isinstance(p,dict) else p
        accum_pi = []
        accum = 0
        for i in pi:
                accum_pi.append((i[0],i[1]+accum))
                accum += i[1]
        if accum == 0:
                raise Exception( "You are about to explode the universe. Continue ? Y/N " )
        normed_a = []
        for a in accum_pi:
                normed_a.append((a[0],a[1]*1.0/accum))
        return normed_a
```

Yields:

```
>>> accumulate_normalize_values( { 'a': 100, 'b' : 300, 'c' : 400, 'd' : 200  } )
[('a', 0.1), ('c', 0.5), ('b', 0.8), ('d', 1.0)]
```

**Why it works**

The **accumulation** step turns each symbol into an interval between itself and the previous symbols probability or frequency (or 0 in the case of the first symbol). These intervals can be used to select from (and thus sample the provided distribution) by simply stepping through the list until the random number in interval 0.0 -> 1.0 (prepared earlier) is less or equal to the current symbol's interval end-point.

The **normalization** releases us from the need to make sure everything sums to some value. After normalization the "vector" of probabilities sums to 1.0.

The *rest of the code* for selection and generating a arbitrarily long sample from the distribution is below :

```
def select(symbol_intervals,random):
        print symbol_intervals,random
        i = 0
        while random > symbol_intervals[i][1]:
                i += 1
                if i >= len(symbol_intervals):
                        raise Exception( "What did you DO to that poor list?" )
        return symbol_intervals[i][0]


def gen_random(alphabet,length,probabilities=None):
        from random import random
        from itertools import repeat
        if probabilities is None:
                probabilities = dict(zip(alphabet,repeat(1.0)))
        elif len(probabilities) > 0 and isinstance(probabilities[0],(int,long,float)):
                probabilities = dict(zip(alphabet,probabilities)) #ordered
        usable_probabilities = accumulate_normalize_values(probabilities)
        gen = []
        while len(gen) < length:
                gen.append(select(usable_probabilities,random()))
        return gen
```

Usage :

```
>>> gen_random (['a','b','c','d'],10,[100,300,400,200])
['d', 'b', 'b', 'a', 'c', 'c', 'b', 'c', 'c', 'c']   #<--- some of the time
```

Answer (score -1):

Here is a **more effective way** of doing this:

Just call the following function with your 'weights' array (assuming the indices as the corresponding items) and the no. of samples needed. This function can be easily modified to handle ordered pair.

**Returns indexes (or items) sampled/picked (with replacement) using their respective probabilities:**

```
def resample(weights, n):
    beta = 0

    # Caveat: Assign max weight to max*2 for best results
    max_w = max(weights)*2

    # Pick an item uniformly at random, to start with
    current_item = random.randint(0,n-1)
    result = []

    for i in range(n):
        beta += random.uniform(0,max_w)

        while weights[current_item] < beta:
            beta -= weights[current_item]
            current_item = (current_item + 1) % n   # cyclic
        else:
            result.append(current_item)
    return result
```

A short note on the concept used in the while loop. 
We reduce the current item's weight from cumulative beta, which is a cumulative value constructed uniformly at random, and increment current index in order to find the item, the weight of which matches the value of beta.