# Random number with given PDF in Python

Tags: python, random, probability-density

I want to generate an integer random number with a probability distribution function given as a list.
For example if pdf=[3,2,1] then I like 
              rndWDist(pdf)
to return 0,1, and 2, with probabilities of 3/6, 2/6, and 1/6. 
I wrote my own function for that since I couldn't find it in the random module.

```
def randintWDist(pdf):
    cdf=[]
    for x in pdf:
        if cdf:
            cdf.append(cdf[-1]+x)
        else:
            cdf.append(x)
    a=random.randint(1,cdf[-1])
    i=0
    while cdf[i]<a:
        i=i+1
    return i
```

Is there any shorter method to achieve the same result?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Generate random numbers with a given (numerical) distribution](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4265988/generate-random-numbers-with-a-given-numerical-distribution)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is a duplicate question: [Generate random numbers with a given (numerical) distribution](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4265988/1449104)

As the first answer there suggest, you might want to use [`scipy.stats.rv_discrete`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.rv_discrete.html).

You might use it like that:

```
from scipy.stats import rv_discrete
numbers = (1,2,3)
distribution = (1./6, 2./6, 3./6)
random_variable = rv_discrete(values=(numbers,distribution))
random_variable.rvs(size=10)
```

This returns a numpy array with 10 random values.

Answer (score 1):

Given the format of your input, you could do:

```
def randint_with_dist(pdf):
    choices = []
    for index, value in enumerate(pdf):
        choices.extend(index for _ in range(value))
    return random.choice(choices)
```

As the same list will be used every time the same `pdf` is passed, you could consider caching the list for greater efficiency (at the cost of space):

```
def randint_with_dist(pdf, choices={}):
    pdf = tuple(pdf)
    if pdf not in choices:
        choices[pdf] = []
        for index, value in enumerate(pdf):
            choices[pdf].extend(index for _ in range(value))
    return random.choice(choices[pdf])
```

Answer (score 1):

Using numpy (version 1.7 or newer), you could also use [np.random.choice](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-dev/reference/generated/numpy.random.choice.html):

```
In [27]: import numpy as np

In [28]: distribution = (1./6, 2./6, 3./6)

In [29]: np.random.choice(np.arange(len(distribution)), p=distribution)
Out[29]: 0

In [30]: np.random.choice(np.arange(len(distribution)), p=distribution, size=10)
Out[30]: array([2, 1, 1, 2, 2, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0])
```