# Histogram distribution in Python

Tags: python, scipy, histogram, distribution

How is it possible to generate histogram distribution in Python? For example, I would like my bins to have the following limits [0, 0.75, 1.5, 2.25, 3.0, 3.75].
Each number in bin is equally likely to occur, with following probabilities (0.755, 0.180, 0.040, 0.018, 0.007) for particular bin.
I would like to use scipy.stats and later rvs() module.

Comment: You may want to be more specific here. What kind of answer do you expect from us? Requesting a full implementation is way too broad for stackoverflow.

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4265988/generate-random-numbers-with-a-given-numerical-distribution and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25642599/random-number-with-given-pdf-in-python/25643622#25643622