# Sample from a discrete random distribution in Python

Tags: python-3.x, distribution, discrete-space

I was hoping to know if there is a command in numpy of scipy to pick an element of a data from a discrete random distribution. i.e.,

For example I have a discrete distribution `x = (0.5, 0.3, 0.2)` and I want to sample from `y = (1, 2, 3)`...

```
>>> sample(x, y)
2
>>> sample(x, y)
3
>>> sample(x, y)
3
>>> sample(x, y)
1
```

Hope my question is clear. Thanks.

Comment: What do you mean by "sample"?

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I updated the question but what I was hoping to do is to pick an element of an array data based on a discrete distribution stored in an array with the same dimension as the data.

Comment: Is each element of x the probability that the corresponding element of y should be selected?

Comment: Yes it is...I was thinking of placing them in a dict and trying to create a function for it but I was wondering if it exists in numpy or scipy already...Thanks.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Generate random numbers with a given (numerical) distribution](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4265988/generate-random-numbers-with-a-given-numerical-distribution)