# Set variable to different value based on probability

Tags: python, probability, either

I have a variable, x, and I want to set it to the values either 1 or 2, with a 60% probability x=1 and a 40% x=2.

I'm doing this in a class, so x should regenerate each time a button is clicked and I'll then plot it, but I'm not sure how to set it using specific probabilities. I know I could do it randomly but that's not quite what I want.

Does anyone know how to do this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [A weighted version of random.choice](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3679694/a-weighted-version-of-random-choice)

Comment: also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4265988/generate-random-numbers-with-a-given-numerical-distribution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple strategy could be the following:

1. generate a random number between 0-1
2. if random number is greater than 0.6 assign value 2
3. else assign value 1

Python code to do this:

```
import random
if random.random() > 0.6:
  x = 2
else:
  x = 1
```

Answer (score 2):

Random uses a uniform distribution, so you can use it like this :

```
x = 1 if random.random() < 0.6 else 2
```

Answer (score 1):

You just take a random value, check if it is less than desired probablility, and return the first or the second option:

```
def random_choice(val1, val2, probability_of_val1):
    return val1 if random.random() < probability_of_val1 else val2
```