# how to generate a random number with a known probability?

Tags: python-3.x, random, random-seed

I would like to generate a random number between `x` and `y` with a known probability. For example, using  `Output=randint(0,2)`  i know that there is a 33% probability that `Output` is equal to 1.

Similarly, if `Output=randint(0,3)` i know that there is 25% probability that the `Output` is equal to 1.

How can i generate a random number similar to above to make sure that there is 40% probability that `Output` equal to 1?

Thanks a lot

Comment: If you are looking for a batteries-included solution, have a look at numpy: https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.random.choice.html. If you want to implement it yourself, the key insight is that you can reduce this problem to drawing a random float between 0 and 1 using the cumulative density function.

Comment: `1 if random() < 0.4 else 0`? Surely this must be a duplicate.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Generate random numbers with a given (numerical) distribution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4265988/generate-random-numbers-with-a-given-numerical-distribution)

Comment: Using a cumulative density function is a really good point? do you mean normal density?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure what's your aim here, how about getting 40% by giving a fixed range, and than manipulating the results?

For example, this will give you 40% value of 1, and 30% of 2 or 3

```
num = randint(0,9)

if num <= 3:
   num = 1
elif num <= 6:
   num = 2
else:
   num = 3
```

Comment: I like this simple approach. I ll go for that thanks a lot. i am doing a simple testing on some randomization problem so i am looking for a quick and dirty approach

Answer (score 1):

Here I have an alternative solution, looks shorter and since there are no `if` statements it should be much faster.
Also, you can easily change what number is to be returned with the 60% probability

```
a = [1,1,0,0,0]
num = a[randint(0,4)]
```

As alternative here is a version of the same with a single line:

```
num = list((1,1,0,0,0))[randint(0,4)]
```