# Generate random vectors with a given (numerical) distribution matrix

Tags: python, numpy, optimization, pytorch

I'm trying to come up with a fast and smart way of generating random vectors from a distribution matrix, much like what is being discussed here:
[Generate random numbers with a given (numerical) distribution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4265988/generate-random-numbers-with-a-given-numerical-distribution)

But the key difference is that I have a distribution matrix, rather than just a single vector.

Now obviously I could just create a for loop and loop over each vector in my matrix, but that doesn't seem very pythonic, or fast, so I'm kinda hoping that there is a better way of doing it.

To give a quick example of what I want to do:
Given a one-probability matrix

```
p = [[0.2, 0.4, 0.4],[0.1, 0.7, 0.2],[0.44, 0.5, 0.06],...]
```

I wish to draw elements, where each element gets selected with the probability in the probability matrix. (Essentially I want to generate a one-hot encoding from my one-probability matrix).
Which could for instance look like this given the above probabilities:

```
t = [2,1,2,...]
```

I need to do this for long sequences, and I need to do it millions of times, but only 1 time for each sequence each time. (Data augmentation for deep learning)

Does anyone have a good way of doing this?

Comment: I think that will work yeah!
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use inverse transform sampling. Compute a cumulative distribution on your p matrix, sample a single random vector of size the height of the matrix, then return the largest index along each row of the cumulative matrix. In code:

```
p = np.array([[0.2, 0.4, 0.4],[0.1, 0.7, 0.2],[0.44, 0.5, 0.06]])
u = np.random.rand(p.shape[0])
idxs = (p.cumsum(1) < u).sum(1)
```

then the `idxs` will be sampled according to the rows of p. e.g.:

```
np.histogram((p[0].cumsum() < np.random.rand(10000,1)).sum(1), bins=3)
# array([1977, 4018, 4005]), ...
```

Comment: This seems to be the same strategy posted in mathfux link, and it seems like a good solution. Thanks!