# landau Random number generator

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, pyroot

I am trying to generate 1000 values with landau distribution with an MPV(most probable value) of 25, can't find a landau random number generator in scipy or numpy. I tried pylandau {`pip install pylandau`} but this seems to only fit landaus and not generate random numbers. Any way of doing this would be welcome in python or pyroot.

Comment: I don't understand what you are trying to do. Can you provide us with more detail?

Comment: Is it clearer now?

Comment: I think it this not exist in Python. Probably you know this paper: K.S. Kolbig and B. Schorr, A program package for the Landau distribution, Computer Phys. Comm. 31 (1984) 97–111

Answer (score 0):

The package [pylandau](https://pypi.org/project/pylandau/) is just calculating the Landau function value. It can be used for fitting, random number generation, etc.
It seems like you would like to know how to generate random numbers from a distribution, as answered in another question
[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4265988/generate-random-numbers-with-a-given-numerical-distribution). The following example creates 100 random values from the Landau distribution:

```py
import numpy as np
import pylandau

x = np.arange(-1, 1, 0.01)
y = pylandau.landau(x)
random_values = np.random.choice(x, size=100, p=y / y.sum())
```

Answer (score 0):

[landaupy](https://github.com/SengerM/landaupy) implements a pure-Python implementation of the Landau (and Langauss) distribution and allows to generate random samples. The code would be

```py
from landaupy import landau

samples = landau.sample(x_mpv=25, xi=1, n_samples=1000)
```

You can install this with

```
pip install git+https://github.com/SengerM/landaupy
```