# Creating a list that uses a dictionary that has percentages

Tags: python, dictionary

I am a noob when It comes to using python, so I have a question in regards to creating a list based off a dictionary.

So let's say I have something like:

```
fruits =       { 'Oranges%' : 30.0, 
                 'Apples%' :  20.0,
                 'Grapes%' : 35.0,
                 'Bananas%' : 15.0}`
```

The value in the dictionary is the percentage of how often it could appear on the output. How would I go about creating a function that follows the percentages? I know the random feature is included in there but I don't know how to do it. Any pointers would be helpful!

Edit: to give more details, I would want the list to randomly generate the names of the fruit based off of the percentages.

```
def generate_list(length, fruits):
import random
fruit_list = ''
for i in range(length):
    num = random.uniform(0, 99)
    if num < fruits['Oranges%']:
        fruit_list = fruit_list + 'oranges'
    elif num < fruits['Oranges%'] + fruits['Apples%']:
        fruit_list = fruit_list + 'apples'
    elif num < fruits['Oranges%'] + fruits['Apples%'] + fruits['Grapes%']:
        fruit_list = fruit_list + 'Grapes'
    else:
        fruit_list = fruit_list + 'Bannana' 
return fruit_list
```

Edit 2: I would want the code to do something like this, but I do not know what I am doing wrong.

Comment: I have no idea what you're asking. Could you try to do it, and post a [MCVE] of what isn't working if you have trouble? Right now I don't know what you actually want it to do...

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour]. If this is homework, please read [How do I ask and answer homework questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/334822/4518341) I think you're looking for [`random.choices(weights=fruits.values())`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.choices), but it's not clear how exactly you want to use it. For tips, see [ask].

Comment: @ShadowRanger:  I suspect OP wants a random generator that returns 'Oranges' 30% of the time, 'Apples' 20% of the time, etc.

Comment: What Frank said! I just don't know how to make it into a code. Sorry about the confusion

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Generate random numbers with a given (numerical) distribution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4265988/generate-random-numbers-with-a-given-numerical-distribution)

Answer (score 1):

Use [`choices` in the random module](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/random.html#random.choices):

```
from random import choices
fruits =       { 'Oranges%' : 0.3, 
                 'Apples%' :  0.2,
                 'Grapes%' : 0.35,
                 'Bananas%' : 0.15}

population = list(fruits.keys())
weights = list(fruits.values())
my_list = choices(population, weights, k=100) #Generates 100 items
print(my_list)
```

First we get the objects in the dictionary, and convert them to a list, then we pass our lists into the `random.choices` function with `k=100` to generate 100 objects, and finally we print it out.

Output:

```
['Grapes%', 'Grapes%', 'Bananas%', 'Oranges%', 'Oranges%', 'Grapes%', 'Apples%', 'Grapes%', 'Apples%', 'Apples%', 'Grapes%', 'Oranges%', 'Oranges%', 'Apples%', 'Grapes%', 'Oranges%', 'Grapes%', 'Oranges%', 'Oranges%', 'Bananas%', 'Bananas%', 'Oranges%', 'Oranges%', 'Grapes%', 'Apples%', 'Grapes%', 'Grapes%', 'Grapes%', 'Grapes%', 'Apples%', 'Bananas%', 'Grapes%', 'Bananas%', 'Grapes%', 'Apples%', 'Apples%', 'Grapes%', 'Grapes%', 'Oranges%', 'Grapes%', 'Grapes%', 'Apples%', 'Apples%', 'Grapes%', 'Oranges%', 'Grapes%', 'Grapes%', 'Grapes%', 'Oranges%', 'Apples%', 'Oranges%', 'Oranges%', 'Grapes%', 'Oranges%', 'Oranges%', 'Apples%', 'Apples%', 'Grapes%', 'Grapes%', 'Grapes%', 'Oranges%', 'Bananas%', 'Oranges%', 'Grapes%', 'Apples%', 'Oranges%', 'Bananas%', 'Apples%', 'Oranges%', 'Grapes%', 'Oranges%', 'Oranges%', 'Grapes%', 'Apples%', 'Oranges%', 'Bananas%', 'Apples%', 'Grapes%', 'Oranges%', 'Grapes%', 'Oranges%', 'Grapes%', 'Grapes%', 'Oranges%', 'Bananas%', 'Oranges%', 'Oranges%', 'Oranges%', 'Bananas%', 'Grapes%', 'Bananas%', 'Grapes%', 'Grapes%', 'Oranges%', 'Apples%', 'Oranges%', 'Oranges%', 'Bananas%', 'Grapes%', 'Oranges%']
```

> The `choices()` method returns a list with the randomly selected
> element from the specified sequence.
>
> You can weigh the possibility of each result with the weights
> parameter or the cum_weights parameter.
>
> The sequence can be a string, a range, a list, a tuple or any other
> kind of sequence.

Answer (score 0):

This could not be easier.

```
import random

fruits = ['Orange','Apple','Grape','Banana']
pcts = [0.3, 0.2, 0.35, 0.15]

fruit_list = random.choices(fruits, k=15, weights=pcts)
print(fruit_list)
```